# Why do we study homology over different rings (that are not even fields)?

Tags: algebraic-topology, modules, homology-cohomology

I am a beginner in this regard, but I believe to have developed a general (geometrically oriented) idea for how to think about homology groups of topological spaces. However, one feature of homology, that I do not yet know what to make of, is that one can develop it over many different fields or rings. That is, the $C_i$ in the chain complex are free $R$-modules for some more or less nicely behaved ring (or even field) $R$.

> **Questions:**
>
> 1. People seem to like studying homology over $R=\Bbb Z$ or other rings that are not fields. But why? Modules over fields (that is, vector spaces) are so much better behaved.
> 2. If $R$ is a field, how much does the choice of field matter. Is there something important about the field besides its characteristic? For example, when does it make a difference whether I work over $\Bbb Q,\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$?
> 3. What is the general idea behind choosing different $R$? When should I choose which? In the case of fields, how do I know what characteristic to work with?

Comment: One little point is that homology over a field cannot "detect" any torsion (that might exist in homology over $\mathbb Z$). This already arises in looking at real projective spaces, which have _torsion_ highest-non-vanishing homology. Also "lens spaces", similarly. On another hand, sometimes it's technically easier to figure out what homology is when torsion is killed of (by some means or other). Trade-offs.

Comment: @paulgarrett Thanks for the comment. This seems plausible. What happens to $\Bbb Z$-homology groups with torsion if I change $R$ into a field. They just vanish? In general, I do not have a good understanding of how homology groups change if I transition from one ringe to another. I could extend my question to also ask whether the homology for different rings is somehow related, but I think my post has sufficiently many subquestion already.

Comment: There are fairly reasonable relations between homology over $\mathbb Z$ and over $\mathbb Q$, for example. You can google "Kunneth formula", for example. I'm by far not an expert, with all my info many decades old, so I hesitate to say much more... :)

Comment: Homology with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_p$ can detect $p$-torsion of various heights if you have enough information about that homology: the Bockstein homomorphism and the higher Bockstein homomorphisms, in particular. The Universal Coefficient Theorem relates integral homology to homology with other coefficients: if you know homology with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$, you can use the UCT to compute with other coefficient groups.

Comment: Actually, @JohnPalmieri's comment about "universal coefficient theorem" is a more direct fact about relations... rather than Kunneth formulas, whose behavior over fields is completely fine, but over other rings becomes trickier. That is, tensor products over fields are vastly simpler than tensor products over $\mathbb Z$...

Answer (score 3):

Homology over $\Bbb Z$ is the most natural and geometric. Chains and homology classes represent geometric loops or higher dimensional holes. Homology over $\Bbb Z_2$ is the next most natural, due to technical reasons, many formulas simplify and make it possible to define cohomology operations like the Steenrod squares. Usually homology over $\Bbb Q$ is studied to eliminate torsion. So basically I think you have it backward, understanding the groups over $\Bbb Z$ is the ultimate goal, being the closest to geometric reality. Over fields is a simplification.

Comment: +1 Just chiming in to say that for smooth manifolds, in particular, working over $\mathbb{R}$ is perhaps in some sense quite  “natural” and geometric, given de Rham theory.

Comment: Two points: one reason why homology over $\mathbb{Z}$ is "geometric" is because of the Hurewicz theorem (the zeroth Postnikov truncation of the sphere is the integers).   The point about $\mathbb{Z}_2$ could be made for any $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for $p$ prime; indeed, when introducing cohomology operations they are probably first made explicit for $\mathbb{Z}_p$, though note they can be defined and are studied for any cohomology theory.